# HTTPS to file in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I need to access a HTTPS Resource which is using Basic Authentication and It is a *GET* Resource. I have written a code in java using `URIBuilder` and adding the username, password etc as Headers to the `URIBuilder` and using Apache `HTTPClient` to access the resource and it is working well.

Now my requirement is to implement the same functionality using *Apache Camel*, Well I tried using *Camel* HTTP component and by using *Java DSL*.

The problem is I am just able to provide the `URI`. But how can I add various Headers to this `URI` ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the [http4 component](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html) as a way to consume this secure resource. From reading the docs of the component you can see it's possible to set the query parameters, path and even uri at runtime.

In answer to your specific question, the headers on the exchange at the point it reaches the .to() will be sent as headers in the HTTP request so you may want to define a header filter strategy. It has support for http basic auth and you can set your credentials via the authUsername and authPassword headers. You may need to provide a custom HttpContext because you're authenticating via https as it suggests at the bottom of the docs. For example:

```
from("direct:in")
    .process(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) {
            //These headers you set here will get sent with the http request in the to() after this processor
            exchange.getIn().setHeader("authUsername", "username");
            exchange.getIn().setHeader("authPassword", "password");
        }
    })
    .to("https4://uri.com);
```

Comment: I checked what you said. But how should I add the Headers to the URI in camel as I was doing in Java. Also  I checked the HttpContext Class, but it has no methods to add the Headers.

Comment: You don't add the headers on the uri you set it on the exchange with exchange.getIn().setHeader("authUsername", "username");

Comment: Thanks for the code. Now I am able to add all the headers which I need in HTTP. But the code is still not working, there is no output on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple language to add headers if you are using blueprint or the java dsl if its pure java. Simple example:

```
from("direct:start")
  .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpMethods.POST))
  .to("http4://www.google.com")
  .to("mock:results");
```